# Splitting and adding to a new column

Tags: python, dataframe

| DIFFERENCE |
| --- |
| 3:52 |
| 0:04 |
| 2:58 |
| 1:21 |
| 2:25 |

I have a column that has time difference in `hh:mm` format.

I need a new column that says: If it is 3:52, I want the new column to have 3 hours 52 minutes as the output. I want to apply that to the whole column in the dataframe.

Thank you.

Comment: what did you already try? Did you look into pandas datetime and the strftime function?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your column is that of a pandas dataframe.

```
import datetime as dt


def format_hhmm(value: str) -> str:
    as_datetime = dt.datetime.strptime(value, "%H:%M")
    return f"{as_datetime.hour} hours {as_datetime.minute} minutes"


df['difference_human_readable'] = df['DIFFERENCE'].apply(format_hhmm)
```

This will create a new column called "difference_human_readable" that row wise applies the string formatting function "format_hmm". This assumes your values are string.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd


def convert_time(value):
    time = value.split(':')
    return f'{time[0]} hours {time[1]} minutes'


df = pd.DataFrame({'Difference': ['3:52', '0:04', '2:58', '1:21', '2:25']})
df['Diff_str'] = df['Difference'].apply(convert_time)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibile solutions. One of them is to .apply() a transformation function:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({"DIFFERENCE": [
    "3:52",
    "0:04",
    "2:58",
    "1:21",
    "2:25"
]})

def conversion(date):
    return date.split(":")[0] + " hours " + date.split(":")[1] + " minutes"

df["DIFFERENCE_2"] = df["DIFFERENCE"].apply(conversion)

print(df)
```